# Why do CUDA kernels get slowed down by CPU code?

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I have write a masked template matching algorithm using CUDA. The functionality of the algorithm is correct, as I have tested. However, when I try to compare the CUDA implementation of the algorithm with the OpenCV implementation using the following piece of code, something strange happens.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    // ---------------------------------------- GPU --------------------------------------------
    double t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    gpu_img.upload(img);
    matcher->match(gpu_img, gpu_result);    // gpu
    gpu_result.download(result);
    t1 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t1) / cv::getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << t1 * 1000 << std::endl;

    double max_val_gpu;
    double min_val_gpu;
    cv::Point max_loc_gpu;
    cv::minMaxLoc(result, &min_val_gpu, &max_val_gpu, 0, &max_loc_gpu);
    std::cout << "min_val_gpu: " << min_val_gpu << "  max_val_gpu: " << max_val_gpu << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max_loc_gpu: " << max_loc_gpu.x << " " << max_loc_gpu.y << std::endl;
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ---------------------------------------- CPU -----------------------------------------------
    double t4 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    cv::matchTemplate(img, temp, result, 5, mask);  // cpu
    t4 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t4) / cv::getTickFrequency();
    std::cout << "cpu version: " << t4 * 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;

    double min_val_cpu;
    double max_val_cpu;
    cv::Point max_loc_cpu;
    cv::minMaxLoc(result, &min_val_cpu, &max_val_cpu, 0, &max_loc_cpu);
    std::cout << "min_val_cpu: " << min_val_cpu << " max_val_cpu: " << max_val_cpu << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max_loc_cpu: " << max_loc_cpu.x << " " << max_loc_cpu.y << std::endl;
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The time consumption of the CUDA function suddenly increases after several iterations (from 4ms to 20ms).

[image: The time consumption of the cuda function]

I have tested other CUDA functions, including a simple vector-add and OpenCV CUDA APIs. I find all of these functions could be slowed by CPU codes.

If I run the CPU function twice in each iteration, the time consumption of the CUDA kernel suddenly increases at around 55th iteration (also from 4ms to 20ms). Even if the CPU code is replaced by a single statement waitKey(100), the CUDA kernel still gets slowed.

The code runs on Win10, cuda 11.1; compiled by vs2015 & nvcc 11.1. The GPU is RTX 3060.

Use 'nsys profile' to analyze the performence of the code.

with cpu code:
[image: with cpu code]

without cpu code:
[image: without cpu code]

It seems that all the CUDA APIs and kernels get slowed.

Comment: What kind of system are you running this on? For all we know you could be running on a laptop that starts thermal throttling after ~100 iterations. How does the same graph look for the CPU part?

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the timeline with Nsight Systems (`nsys`) to see what actually takes that long.

Comment: The code runs on Win10. The CPU function runs steadily, which consumes around 90ms all the time.

Comment: If I run the CPU function twice in each iteration, the time consumption of the CUDA kernel suddenly increases at around 55th iteration (also from 4ms to 20ms).

Comment: Try checking with the profiler whether it is the computation or the copying from/to host. If the CPU keeps its RAM busy, the copy can be slower

Comment: Hmmm. Does your program have exclusive use of CUDA when your program is running?  The OS may have to play scheduling algorithms if other tasks or threads are using CUDA.  The CUDA may also need to wait on the CPU for shared resources like memory; the least of which is initializing CUDA.

Comment: The program uses CUDA exclusively.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If the program needs the CPU to feed data to the GPU then the CPU being busy might slow down the GPU since it gets starved of data to process.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory on your GPU for this computation? AFAIK, Windows can store GPU data on the host memory when it does not fit on the GPU memory. This means data need to be transferred from the host memory to the GPU and the other way around. This operation is done at the page level and it is very expensive. `nvidia-smi` can be used to check that easily I think.

Comment: Device 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU; 
Compute capability: 8.6; 
Total global memory: 6143 MB; 
Max thread per block: 1024; 
Max grid dimensions: 2147483647x65535; 
Device Overlap: 1;

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the NVIDIA GPU would slown down its clock frequency when the CUDA kernel gets starved of data to process. This problem could be solved by setting Nvidia Control Panel and using `nvidia-smi -lgc` to fix the clock frequency.